# In iPhone Simulator, how to type the @ sign on a macbook with German keyboard?

Tags: ios, macos, ios-simulator

Question in the topic. I couldn't find anything in google. Friend of mine has same problem:

When running an app in the iPhone Simulator and I want to type an email address into a text field, I can't do this using the normal MacBook's keyboard. When I use the normal way to type the @ sign (Alt+L), what I get in the simulator is the mathematical negation symbol (¬) instead of @.

My keyboard settings in the Mac are correct otherwise.

As you can see, the @ sign is located on the L key, which also works when working e.g. in a text editor on the Mac:
[image: Here is a photo of my MacBook's keyboard]

When holding down the Alt key, the simulation of a pinch-gesture is started. Maybe it has to do with this functionality. Can I assign this feature to another key?

Comment: Just use the onscreen iOS Simulator keyboard?

Comment: Try it with copy paste.

Comment: what is your keyboard type qwert or azerty

Comment: my keyboard is a qwert

Comment: @LordT, that's what I do, but when I have to type more text for testing, interleaved with email addresses and normal text, I often have to switch between mouse and keyboard and this is slow and very cumbersome. I try to work efficiently.

Comment: close-voters, this question is about "software tools commonly used by programmers", hence it is valid for SO. Do not close.

Comment: What I usually do in these surcumstances is copy'n'paste. IE cmd+c it in the normal os, cmd+v it in the simulator and the long-click and paste in iOS! But other then that, I code with an american layout to get around these issues :)

Comment: close-voters, you made a mistake. You stated the reason "questions, which ... are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming**". The iPhone Simulator is clearly a tool primarily used for programming, so this question has a right to be here. This question is not about how to type the @ sign on a German keyboard. Doing this is very simple and it works. The only thing which doesn't work in this regard is the iPhone Simulator, which is the programming tool this question is about.

Comment: same question for french keyboard. Seems to be ALT+*

Answer (score 10):

Try `shift+2` you can also change the keyboard on the simulator to german in the settings and try again. And u can try using the mouse when the keyboard pops up on the simulator.

Comment: shift+2 and alt+shift+2 didn't work for me. I'm getting a " or ” with that.

Comment: If i google german keyboard layout is @ sign is located under the Q ??

Comment: changing language to german was promising, but didn't help. it's still the same sign.

Comment: Did you try the Q with alt or alt+shift of alt+ctrl. Google says the Q holds the @ sign in a german keyboard. And on google images i see the @ sign also under Q.

Comment: the Q also didn't work, neither with shift, alt, nor both.

Comment: Than i can't help you any further, i live near Germany but i don't own a German keyboard. Good luck.

Comment: if shift+2 doesnt work, try out alt-G

Comment: use option k to show the software keyboard. There you have access to the at sign.

Comment: alt+* on french keyboard

Comment: ALT+L worked for me!

Comment: For me - ALT-GR + L did the trick

Answer (score 1):

both are different iOS and Mac OS. so you use directly iphone keyboard not use system keyboard directly both are may be different functionality for different shortcut keys

[image]

set your textfield keyboard type

```
  [textField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
```

Edited:

On Macintosh OS X, you can use the operating system’s character palette to find special characters. Press command+option+T to make the character palette window appear.

The character palette will also show up as a menu item in the keyboard menu if the keyboard menu is displayed in the top right of your menu bar. The keyboard menu shows as a flag corresponding to the currently active keyboard layout.

New Answer

Writer for iPad and iPhone includes a keyboard extension bar, which gives you navigation buttons, plus quick access to language-specific punctuation. The keyboard bar has localized keys for the following keyboards in Writer for iPad: Arabic, Simplified Chinese, Traditional Chinese, Croatian, Dutch, English, French, Swiss French, Canadian French, German, Swiss German, Greek, Italian, Japanese, Latvian, Polish, Portuguese, Romanian, Russian, Spanish, and Ukrainian.

Here are some other ways to type special characters, both on iOS and in Mac OS X.

http://support.iawriter.com/help/kb/general-questions/typing-spe

Comment: Was worth a try, but didn't help either.

Comment: I can use the @ sign on the soft-keyboard of the iPhone Simulator. That works, but it's not efficient. I always have to switch to the mouse while typing, just for putting in one character. That nags the crap out of you when you have to do lots of testing.